# Table view cell accessory not changing when out of view

Tags: swift

I have this piece of code:

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
if let selected = self.lastSelected {
   tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selected)?.accessoryType = .None
}
tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
self.lastSelected = indexPath
```

I allows me to place a checkmark on the cell that I select and removes the previous checkmark. The problem I am having is that if the list is large and the cell is out of view, the checkmark is not removed when a new cell is selected.

I have tried adding tableview.reloaddata() but that did nothing.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `nil` for non-visible cells.

To get a radio button like effect, you need to do something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath

    // Note indexPathsForVisibleRows may be nil depending on your app's content.
    // zip just joins two arrays together, into a single array of tuples.
    zip(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, tableView.visibleCells).forEach({ indexPath, cell in
        configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    })
}
```